# Using string variable in another form C#

Tags: c#

No matter what I try, I keep getting "The name 'userName' does not exist in the current context." I'm trying to pass a username and login from a login form to a field on the main form. I have set these field modifiers as Public. I've tried creating an instance of the LoginForm class, but I get the same behavior.

**LoginForm.cs**

```
public void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = User.Text;
        string password = Password.Text;

        this.Visible = false;
    }
```

**MainForm.cs**

```
public void Browser_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Browser.Document.GetElementById("Email").InnerText = userName;
        Browser.Document.GetElementById("Password").InnerText = password;
    }
```

Comment: The (local) variable is not in scope. It would be worthwhile to read a C# tutorial.

Comment: "I'm trying to pass a username and login from a login form to a field on the main form" .... nothing in your code example demonstrates doing that in any way ...

Comment: Okay, I got the errors out by creating an instance of the loginForm, then passing the text from loginForm to a variable. But it still does not act as I intend.  The first form contains textboxes User and Password. When the submit button is clicked, it stores these into variables. The variables should then be sent to fields on page within a WebBrowser control. I know that the Id's are correct, because I can replace the userName variable with a string and it will fill the Email field.

Comment: @user3341951 the idea is that you post this code, not explaining or describing the code, so we can understand what goes wrong and try to help you make it work.

Comment: @user3341951 - "The variables should then be sent to fields..." why? You're creating a new instance of `loginForm` - it's not the same instance that the `WebBrowser` control is on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this, when you create the LoginForm Window?
Make sure your TextBoxes are set as public..

```
var loginform = new LoginForm();
loginform.textbox1.TextChangedEvent += new textbox1_TextChangedEvent();
loginform.textbox2.TextChangedEvent += new textbox2_TextChangedEvent();
loginform.Show(); //Can also use loginform.ShowDialog();


void textbox1_TextChangedEvent(object sender, Eventarg e)
{
  textbox1_Username.Text == ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}

void textbox2_TextChangedEvent(object sender, Eventarg e)
{
  textbox2_Password.Text == ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

This might give you an idea on how to do it, just run the events on the mainform and don't create them on the loginform directly..

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try to do is declare the variables outside of the control itself. then refer to the main control.variable like this if I remember right
(pseudo-code since I didn't proof check it)

First make the variable outside like this

```
public string userName;
public string password;
public void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userName = User.Text;
    password = Password.Text;

    this.Visible = false;
}
```

then

```
Browser.Document.GetElementById("Email").InnerText = LoginForm.UserName
```

modify and correct the code as needed. cheers